# Liaison et enchaînement

Tags: liaisons

> Les embarras de M. Dupont et de Madame, privés hier d'électricité,
>   furent innombrables

Est-ce qu'il me faut faire un enchaînement entre les mots « furent » et « innombrables » ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La liaison entre *furent* et *innombrables* est facultative, /fyʁinɔ̃bʁabl/ ou /fyʁtinɔ̃bʁabl/ contrairement à *les embarras* ou la liaison est obligatoire, /lezɑ̃baʁa/.

C'est assez bien expliqué ici : [https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liaison_en_français#Liaison_interdite](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liaison_en_fran%C3%A7ais#Liaison_interdite)

Answer (score 3):

La liaison entre les formes du verbe être et l'attribut du sujet ne sont ni obligatoires, ni interdites. Elles sont donc facultatives. cf. [Wikipedia](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liaison_en_fran%C3%A7ais#Liaison_facultative).

Dans le langage soutenu, on fera la liaison alors que dans un contexte plus courant, elle sera souvent omise et la fin de la phrase prononcée comme *furie nombrable*. Le passé simple est cependant plus souvent associé à un registre élevé.

Answer (score 1):

Bonjour Claire,

> **Les embarras de Monsieur et Madame Dupont, privés hier d'électricité, furent innombrables.**

serait plus juste. Toutefois : **"embarras"** me semble inapproprié, car c'est un sentiment *proche de la honte* ; je pense que **"tracas"** ou **"mésaventures"** est plus correct. Pour la question principale : **oui**, il faut faire une liaison entre **"furent"** et **"innombrables"** (*"furti nombrable"* à l'oral).

Answer (score 0):

Pensez que les liaisons sont recommandées et surtout constituent l'un des meilleurs discriminants sociaux de maîtrise du langage. Peut-être l'exemple le plus caricatural est celui de 
"Comment allez-vous" à prononcer obligatoirement "comment Tallez-vous".
Si vous omettez systématiquement les liaisons, vous appauvrissez la langue parlée et vous vous placez vous-même dans une situation d'infériorité dans l'échelle sociale.